# Using PHP to build HTML Hyperlinks... Syntax Question

Tags: php, html, url

I'm an PHP newbie trying to figure out how to use the language to build HTML hyperlinks.  I'd like code that produces this HTML-ready code:

```
<a href="http://10.10.10.10/bigLongStringHere">LINK1</a>
```

Here's the PHP code I'm tinkering with at the moment:

```
$someString = "bigLongStringHere";

$URL1 = "<a href=\"http://10.10.10.10/".$someString.">LINK1</a>";
print("= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =\n");
print("URL1  ::  ".$URL1."\n");
print("URL1  ::  $URL1\n");
print("URL1  ::  \"$URL1\"\n");
```

When I run the above code in my browser, I get this output:

```
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
URL1  ::  _LINK1_
URL1  ::  "
```

That "*LINK1*" in the `URL1  ::  _LINK1_` line is actually a hyperlink.  When I hover my mouse over that hyperlink, the browser says the hyperlink is:

```
http://10.10.10.10/bigLongStringHere%3ELINK1%3C/a%3EURL1%20%20::%20%20%3Ca%20href=
```

...which I think translates to this...?

```
http://10.10.10.10/bigLongStringHere>LINK1</a>URL1::<ahref=
```

I'm not sure, and have been fumbling with this for hours.  Does anyone see my error?  Thank you.

Comment: You haven't closed off the string value of `href`. `$URL1 = "<a href=\"http://10.10.10.10/".$someString."\">LINK1</a>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```php
$someString = "bigLongStringHere";

echo '<p>URL1:: <a href="http://10.10.10.10/' . $someString . '">LINK</a></p>';
```

It will output this:
URL1:: [LINK](http://10.10.10.10/bigLongStringHere)

Comment: As you are using single quotes around the main string - any variables will not be interpreted.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was typing that on phone. I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the function "echo"

```
<?php

    $someString = "bigLongStringHere";
    
    $URL1 = '<a href="http://10.10.10.10/'.$someString.'">LINK1</a>';

    echo $URL1
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: Wouldn't make a difference and still missing the href closing `"`

Answer (score 1):

I see a few ways to do this.

The first method split the PHP and HTML out like this, allowing you to easily manipulate the HTML without impacting the PHP code

```php
<?php
    $baseUrl = "http://10.10.10.10";
    $pageUrl = "bigLongStringHere";
?>

<a href="<?= $baseUrl; ?><?= $pageUrl; ?>">Click Here</a>
```

The other, and probably better, solution is to take advantage of PHP being a loosely typed language like this:

```php
$somestring = "abcdefq";
$url = '<a href="http://10.10.10.10/'.$someString.'">LINK1</a>';
echo($url);
```

This means you don't have to deal with escaping the double quotes.